# como eliminar TODOS los elementos de un arreglo

Tags: python, django

En un arreglo guardo todo el formato de una tabla que estoy colocando en un PDF, lo hago dentro de un **for**.

A la siguiente vuelta me coloca lo primero y lo segundo, cuando solo tiene que colocar lo segundo por ser la segunda vuelta.

¿Cómo puedo eliminar el contenido de un arreglo TODOS para que se limpie?

```
for vuelta in range(mes,13):

    tabla_formateada = []
            vuelta=1
            for item in tabla_encabezado:
                tabla_formateada.append(Paragraph("<font size=%s><b>%s</b></font>" % (6, item),
                                                   rep.styles_reporte()['center']))
                vuelta=vuelta + 1
                if vuelta > 4:
                    tabla_formateada.append(Paragraph("<font size=%s><b>%s</b></font>" % (6, '%'),
                                                      rep.styles_reporte()['center']))
     tabla1 = [tabla_formateada]

     ano_inicio = int(ano_inicio) + 1

     '''se les da el tamaño a cada una de las columnas'''
      table = Table(tabla1, colWidths=tamano,
                      repeatRows=1)

      '''se le agrega el estilo ala tabla'''
      table.setStyle([('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),
                        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.30, colors.black),
                        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 
     colors.HexColor('#DFDFDF')),
                        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, 
     colors.black)])
        story.append(table)
        story.append(Spacer(1, 10 * mm))

    doc.build(story)
    buff.close()

    buff = open(RECURSOS_DIR + '/pdf/vencimientos_tnr_mensual.pdf', 'rb')
    response.write(buff.read())
```

Comment: es demasiado codigo

Comment: ya coloque algo para ver si puedes ayudar, por favor

Comment: ya lo hice amigo, espero me puedas ayudar

Comment: tabla 1 - es la variable que guarda todo el contenido y por que cada vuelta que da el for me agrega una tabla en el PDF pero, con la tabla anterior, es por eso que necesito borrar o limpiar ese arreglo

Comment: ya esta amigo, hice lo mejor que puede, espero ahora si me puedas ayudar, no encuentro una solucion

Comment: yo particularmente no se nada de python, pero con una buena pregunta tenes mas posibilidades de que alguien pueda contestarte!

Comment: tabla 1 - es la variable que guarda todo el contenido y por que cada vuelta que da el for me agrega una tabla en el PDF pero, con la tabla anterior, es por eso que necesito borrar o limpiar ese arreglo

Comment: Yo no alcanzo a ver el fallo, ¿has probado a hacer tabla1 = [] al inicio del bucle? aunque no debería hacer falta...

Comment: si ya lo intente y me coloca la variable en "negrita" como no existiera

Comment: también cambiaría el nombre del contador vuelta que utilizas, se pude confundir con el contador del bucle.

Comment: ya lo intente y sigue fallando, me sigue colocando lo de la primera vuelta en la segunda

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar una foto de lo que te devuelve? he intentado reproducir tu código y no termino de entenderlo..

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81593/discussion-between-xboss-and-jonathan-garcia).